# Sharing session data between ASP.NET and PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, session, session-variables

I'm building a custom .net web app with a wordpress frontpage and CMS.

I'm using session variables to check if the user is logged in to the web app.

What I'd like to be able to do is display on wordpress whether or not the user is logged in to the webapp.

Is this possible and if so does anybody know how I would go about doing it?

Thanks, 
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cookie and a database. The cookie contains some unique ID for that session, which you store in the database. Nothing specific to asp.net or php about cookies. Either app can obtain the key from the cookie, and look up the session info in the database.